# Why are assertEquals() parameters in the order (expected, actual)?

Tags: python, debugging, assert

Why do so many [`assertEquals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) or similar functions take the expected value as the first parameter and the actual one as second?
This seems counterintuitive to me, so is there a particular reason for this unusual order?

Comment: This is why I usually end up using matchers, such as assertThat(actual, is(expected)) I find it so much easier to read

Comment: Are you sure that really is the order? The docs don't indicate a standard for `assertEqual` itself https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual and browsing that page shows the order is inconsistent within the unittest module itself. But this Python issue implies (actual, expected) is, in fact, the standard: http://bugs.python.org/issue10573

Comment: Also, note that `assertEquals` is deprecated—use `assertEqual` (even though, at least in 2.7, it doesn't actually indicate which parameter is expected and which is actual)

Comment: @MichaelScheper http://bugs.python.org/file20580/expected-actual.diff

Comment: @warvariuc: Looks like they've gone from 'expected' and 'actual' to 'first' and 'second'. I think this makes unit tests more ambiguous and test output more difficult to understand. Any idea why they changed it this way?

Comment: @MichaelScheper for me `self.assertEqual(actual, expected)` is more logical than `self.assertEqual(expected, actual)`: `if smth == other:` -> `assert smth == other` -> `self.assertEqual(smth, other)`. For me this is the usual order, I have yet to find out why others think different.

Comment: @warvariuc: I don't have any strong feelings about the order of 'actual' and 'expected', as long as it's consistent, and above all, the parameters are clearly named. But in the diff you linked to, it appears the parameters have been renamed to 'first' and 'second'. These aren't just unclear, but practically meaningless! With those names, I can't tell whether the failure message for`self.assertEqual(ltuae, 42)` will say 42 was expected, or 54. If a test fails, I want the message to be helpful and accurate, so the bug can be fixed as quickly as possible; the new parameter names make that harder.

Comment: @JonathanC, are you speaking about https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest?

Comment: I would say that there is a case for arguing that the convention is `assertEqual(actual, expected)`, the opposite of what the question post states. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398660/247696

Comment: Because it is/was the correct order! see also: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/3aQU5iM5Ov0/m/7OlMoCtxBgAJ?pli=1

Answer (score 56):

The [answer](https://sourceforge.net/p/junit/mailman/message/3338997/) from [Kent Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck), co-creator of JUnit (where possibly this convention [originates](https://www.javadoc.io/static/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit/framework/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), since his earlier SUnit [doesn't appear to have included `assertEquals`](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002201843/https://swing.fit.cvut.cz/projects/stx/doc/online/english/tools/misc/testfram.htm)):

> Line a bunch of assertEquals in a row. Having expected first makes them read better.

In the initial version of my answer, I said that I didn't understand this. Here's what I often see in tests:

```java
assertEquals(12345, user.getId());
assertEquals("kent", user.getUsername());
assertEquals("Kent Beck", user.getName());
```

I would think this would read better with the *actual* value first. That puts more of the repetitive boilerplate together, aligning the method calls whose values we're testing:

```java
assertEquals(user.getId(), 12345);
assertEquals(user.getUsername(), "kent");
assertEquals(user.getName(), "Kent Beck");
```

(And there are other reasons that I prefer this order, but for the purpose of this question about *why* it's the other way, Kent's reasoning appears to be the answer.)

However, Bob Stein has [a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404978/why-are-assertequals-parameters-in-the-order-expected-actual/57059952?noredirect=1#comment120750754_57059952) (much like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331259/unit-testing-why-is-the-expected-argument-always-first-in-equality-tests#comment11775091_9331259)) that suggests a couple things that "expected first" has going for it. The main idea is that expected values are probably typically shorter -- often literals or variables/fields, rather than possibly complex method calls. As a result:

- It's easier to identify both the expected and actual values at a glance.
- It's possible to use a small amount of extra whitespace to align them (if you prefer that kind of thing, though I don't see it used in [the earliest JUnit commit I could find easily](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/commit/b6a0693454ac8ded32b3a1ea7c859c5a840169dc#diff-c041ef1fd8f2035b4032f1747f33a35eca4dab8c19fc45c3d3dfb14f64ef31f6R53)):

```java
assertEquals(12345,       user.getId());
assertEquals("kent",      user.getUsername());
assertEquals("Kent Beck", user.getName());
```

Thanks, Bob!

Comment: I think the key to understanding Kent Beck's point is that expected values tend to be shorter. So less whitespace would be needed after the commas to line up the parameters -- assuming one is willing to defy [PEP8's protests against extraneous whitespace](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) of course.

Comment: kudos for your research. Do you think that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9331259/673991) you linked to should be declared a duplicate of this one? If not I think both your and [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53603565/673991) answer belongs there too.

Answer (score 30):

Because the authors had a 50% chance of matching your intuition.

Because of the other overload

```
assertWhatever(explanation, expected, actual)
```

And the explanation, which is part of what you know, goes with the expected, which is what you know, as opposed to the actual, which you don't know at the time you write the code.

Comment: However in that case, it becomes slightly inconsistent because in most languages, the required parameters appear first, and the mandatory ones last.
This is why I would more naturally go for
    assertWhatever(actual, expected [,explanation])

Comment: Exactly, jor! Moreover, it is more common in conditionals to write if(s == "a") rather than if("a"==s) (although it debateable whether it would be better the other way round - in terms of commonness the first one wins though).

Comment: I don't think it is intuitive for 50% of the population... You won't say that `assertGreater(a, b)` asserting `b > a` is intuitive... (and I think that's why they removed the non commutative methods)

Comment: Placing the constant first was something put forth as a way to get an error if you accidentally did an assignment `=` instead of equivalence check `==` as it would throw an error when you tried to re-assign the constant. (I think I first saw it promoted in 'writing solid code')  It creates (IMHO) less readable code (I prefer 'result should be as expected' style grammar) but gets the compiler to bust your chops if you leave out an = sign

Comment: 50% - is human intuition as useless as the flip of a coin? I bet the authors would've had the same intuition with >50% likelihood, if they went off of intuition only. In the western languages I know of, it would be most typical to say "the light switch should be off" rather than "off should be the light switch". Which strongly lends to the order of actual first, then expected. Given the need for consistency with other overloads though, now we have reasons, not just probabilities :)

Answer (score 20):

An ulterior purpose of `assertEqual()` is to demo code for human readers.

A simple function call shows the **return value on the left** and the **call on the right**.

```
    y = f(x)
```

Following that convention, a self-testing demonstration of the function could look like:

```
    assertEqual(y, f(x))
```

The order is (expected, actual).

Here's a demo of the sum() function with a literal **expected** return value on the left, and a function call that calculates the **actual** return value on the right:

```
    assertEqual(15, sum((1,2,3,4,5)))
```

Similarly, here's a demo of an expression. It is also natural in (expected, actual) order:

```
    assertEqual(4, 2 + 2)
```

---

Another reason is stylistic. If you like lining things up, the expected parameter is better on the left because it tends to be shorter:

```
assertEqual(42, 2 * 3 * 7)
assertEqual(42, (1 << 1) + (1 << 3) + (1 << 5))
assertEqual(42, int('110', int('110', 2)))
```

I suspect this solves the mystery [@ChrisPovirk raised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57059952/673991) about what Kent Beck meant by "expected first makes them read better."

<sub>Thanks [Andrew Weimholt](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-complicated-equation-that-is-equal-to-42/answer/Andrew-Weimholt) and [Ganesh Parameswaran](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-complicated-equation-that-is-equal-to-42/answer/Ganesh-Parameswaran) for these formulae.</sub>

Comment: Agreed. I would even put it stronger than "ulterior", possibly "primary motive".  Code is, arguably almost primarily to be read by other developers (and yourself.)  Readability and Comprehendability is a first class concern IMHO.

Comment: @W.Prins man, if we ever did pair-programming, I think we'd either get along great or terrible. It wouldn't be boring. I want to agree, except I can't let go of the feeling that code that won't run is worse than unreadable code. One of the reasons I love asserts is they're sorta guaranteed to run. As much as I feel human factors are underrated in this world, machines still come first. Or maybe I just enjoy the subversive tones of 'ulterior.'

Comment: We are in agreement; I'm not trying to be dogmatic, and I'm not dismissing the execution angle you mention to being unimportant; as you say, it is a "primary" concern IMHO, it's just that (I suggest) this is perhaps taken for granted as being (almost?) the only, or substantially the only important concern in software, a view from which springs IMHO a lot of undesirable side-effects.  I reckon we'd get along fine, I've got opinions but I'm not pedantic or prescriptive.  Life is too short for that, and there's always more than one way to the top of the mountain of working software. :-)

Comment: @W.Prins well said and well agreed on all points. I intuit (as I believe you do) that human factors in coding are underrated and on a long term climb. Viva La Readability!

Answer (score 11):

This is a very intesting topic, and lots of very educational answers here too! Here is what I learn from them:

1. Intuitive/counter-intuitive can be considered as subjective, so no matter which order it was originally defined, perhaps [50% of us would not be happy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405193/728675).
2. Personally I would have preferred it were designed as `assertEqual(actual, expected)`, because, given the conceptual similarity between `assert` and `if`, I would wish it follows [the norm of `if actual == expect`, for example, `if a == 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404978/why-are-assertequals-parameters-in-the-order-expected-actual#comment50037577_2405193).

   (PS: It is true that there are different opinions which [prompts to write if statement in the "reverse order", i.e. `if(1==a) {...}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404978/why-are-assertequals-parameters-in-the-order-expected-actual#comment88277934_2405193), in order to guard you from accidentally missing one `=`. But that style was far from the norm, even in the C/C++ world. And if you happen to be writing Python code, you are not vulnerable to that nasty typo in the first place, because `if a = 1` is not valid in Python.)
3. The practical convincing reason to do `assertEqual(expect, actual)`, is that the unittest library in your language likely already follows that order to generate readable error message. For example, in Python, when you do `assertEqual(expected_dictionary, actual_dictionary)`, [unittest will display missing keys in actual with prefix `-`, and extra keys with prefix `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43033387/728675), just like when you do a `git diff old_branch new_branch`.

   Intuitive or not, this is the single most convincing reason to stick with the `assertEqual(expected, actual)` order. If you happen to not like it, you better still accept it, because ["practicality beats purity"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).
4. Lastly, if you need a way to help you remember the order, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53603565/728675) compares `assertEqual(expected_result, actual_calculation)` to the assignment statement order `result = calculate(...)`. It can be a good way to MEMORIZE the de-facto behavior, but IMHO it is not the undebatable reasoning of that order is more intuitive.

So here you go. Happy `assertEqual(expect, actual)` !

Comment: For the point 4) it's fun enough that the parameter order for assignment was actually much debated in the early ages of computing. Some CS-ists agued that using the order order it could be read "value is stored in value", whjich raised much less confusion with the mathematical equality (and of couse use something different from '=' for assignment like some kind of arrow like '->').

Comment: Nice, but there is a small gotcha: Python unittest's documentation examples (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) clearly show that we should use it like this: `assertEqual(actual, expect)` - so now choose... ;)

Comment: In the early days (about 100 yrs ago) when the first Unit-Test frameworks popped-up did it "expected, actual" order... (because it is logical doing so) Some day a developer did it accidentally actual, expected order... but the tests were green and so that mistake spread like a virus over the whole planet. Decades after that we're still discussing :D (and even unit-test fx developers changed their implementation to make error message readable even if it was done the wrong order, greetings from PISA ;-) ): https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/3aQU5iM5Ov0/m/7OlMoCtxBgAJ?pli=1

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the consensus that consistency is #1, but the behavior of comparing dictionaries may be a helpful data point if you're evaluating this question.

When I see a "+" on a diff, I read this as "the procedure being tested added this." Again, personal preferences apply.

Note: I used alphabetized keys and made the dictionary longer so that only a middle key would change for clarity of the example. Other scenarios display more obfuscated diffs. Also noteworthy, [assertEqual uses assertDictEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertDictEqual) in >=2.7 and >=3.1

#### File *exl.py*

```
from unittest import TestCase


class DictionaryTest(TestCase):

    def test_assert_order(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            {
                'a_first_key': 'value',
                'key_number_2': 'value',
                'z_last_key': 'value',
                'first_not_second': 'value',
            },
            {
                'a_first_key': 'value',
                'key_number_2': 'value',
                'z_last_key': 'value',
                'second_not_first': 'value',
            }
        )
```

Run:

```
python -m unittest exl
```

Output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_assert_order (exl.DictionaryTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exl.py", line 18, in test_assert_order
    'second_not_first': 'value',
AssertionError: {'a_first_key': 'value', 'z_last_key': 'value', 'key_number_2': 'value', 'first_ [truncated]... != {'a_first_key': 'value', 'z_last_key': 'value', 'key_number_2': 'value', 'second [truncated]...
  {'a_first_key': 'value',
-  'first_not_second': 'value',
   'key_number_2': 'value',
+  'second_not_first': 'value',
   'z_last_key': 'value'}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) testing convention is expected/actual. So, for many that is the natural order since that's what they learnt.

Interestingly, in a break from convention for an xUnit framework, qunit goes for actual/expected. At least with JavaScript you can just create a new function that encapsulates the old one and assign it the original variable:

```javascript
var qunitEquals = equals;
equals = function(expected, actual, message) {
    qunitEquals(actual, expected, message);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`assertEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) names the first parameter `first`, and the second parameter `second`:

> `assertEqual(first, second, msg=None)`
>
> Test that `first` and `second` are equal. If the values do not compare equal, the test will fail.

However, if you look at most of the examples in the documentation, they place the received value first, and the expected value second (the opposite of what your question post claims):

> ```
> self.assertEqual(self.widget.size(), (50,50), 'incorrect default size')
> ```

So I would say the convention is `assertEqual(got, expected)`, and not the other way round!

Either way, your tests will still work.

Comment: @warvariuc notes [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404978/why-are-assertequals-parameters-in-the-order-expected-actual/57059952#comment58065419_2404978) that [the parameter names changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue10573) not longer after this question in 2010 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little surprised not to see this answer already, because it's always seemed like the most likely explanation to me.

Imagine you *didn't have* `assertEquals`, but just `assert`. How would you write the test? You might think to write it as:

```
assert(actual == expected)
```

But in many cases, they won't be the same object, just equivalent ones, so (and this is perhaps language-dependent), you can't reliably use the `==` operator to express your intent. So you switch it to:

```
assert(actual.equals(expected))
```

And things are fine for a while. But then you introduce a bug, and the test fails, because the result (actual) becomes ***null***. But the test doesn't fail the way you expect -- instead, you can't even invoke `actual.equals` at all, because you don't even have an object to call a method on! Your test code blows up with an exception because the test itself is fragile.

*But your **expected** object will **never** be null.*

Many people working in OO languages have got used to this, and they make a habit of writing all method-based conditionals like `if ("foo".equals(myString))`, which is still safe in the case that `myString` is null (though the reverse is not safe).

So the *best habit* for writing asserts is:

```
assert(expected.equals(actual))
```

... which fails if actual is wrong, even null.

Once you've spent some years in this kind of situation, and you decide to write a unit testing framework with an `assertEquals` method, there's only one ordering of the arguments that is going to feel natural to you :)

Comment: And yes, obviously, the constraint on nullity is not the same for `assertEquals(x,y)` as it is for `assert(x.equals(y))`. I'm just trying to suggest how the grammar likely evolved.

Answer (score -3):

The explanation I heard is that it comes from [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (TDD).

In test-driven development, you start with the test, and then write the code.

Starting assertions by writing the expectation, and then call the code that should produce it, is a mini version of that mindset.

Of course, this may just be a story people tell. Don't know that it was a conscious reason.

Comment: This may be the **best reason** of any of the answers, though this answer could use some code or visual structure. Notice the original question is present tense, so it's fine to answer what makes sense today versus what developers were thinking when the convention started. In Test-Driven Development, the order is: test, code. That is: results, methods. Or: expected, actual. It's easy to get these confused, but in practice the _expected_ parameter states the results, which is what the **test** needs to know. While _actual_ reveals the methods and invokes the **code**.