# Python: Write unittest for console print

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, console, python-unittest

Function `foo` prints to console. I want to test the console print. How can I achieve this in python?

Need to test this function, has NO return statement :

```
def foo(inStr):
   print "hi"+inStr
```

My test :

```
def test_foo():
    cmdProcess = subprocess.Popen(foo("test"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    cmdOut = cmdProcess.communicate()[0]
    self.assertEquals("hitest", cmdOut)
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998908/is-it-possible-to-mock-pythons-built-in-print-function tl;dr turn print into builtin function using future or assert on replaced stdout file

Comment: I dont want to mock anything. Infact my actual `foo` takes about 8 arguments, and it returns a json. I want to be also to test this.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can easily capture standard output by just temporarily redirecting `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` object, as follows:

```py
import StringIO
import sys
    
def foo(inStr):
    print "hi"+inStr
    
def test_foo():
    capturedOutput = StringIO.StringIO()         # Make StringIO.
    sys.stdout = capturedOutput                  # Redirect stdout.
    foo('test')                                  # Call function.
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__                  # Reset redirect.
    print 'Captured', capturedOutput.getvalue()  # Now works.
    
test_foo()
```

The output of this program is:

```
Captured hitest
```

This shows that the redirection successfully captured the output and that you were able to restore the output stream to what it was before you began the capture.

---

Note that the code above in for Python 2.7, as the question indicates. Python 3 is slightly different:

```py
import io
import sys
    
def foo(inStr):
    print ("hi"+inStr)
    
def test_foo():
    capturedOutput = io.StringIO()                 # Create StringIO.
    sys.stdout = capturedOutput                    # Redirect stdout.
    foo('test')                                    # Call function.
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__                    # Reset redirect.
    print ('Captured', capturedOutput.getvalue())  # Now works.
    
    test_foo()
```

---

You also need to be careful if your function can raise an exception since that may mean that the redirection reset may not be done. This may then affect later tests.

One way to solve that would be to wrap the function call in a `try/except` block and, on exception, reset the redirection and re-throw the exception. The single-line call to your function would then become something like this, with the other code remaining as-is:

```py
try:
    foo('test')                  # Call function.
except:
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  # Reset redirect.
    raise
```

Comment: in Python `3.8.6` use `import io` and `io.StringIO()`. For `SocketIO` I got `AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute 'SocketIO'`.

Comment: @EnriqueRené: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I've had `io.StringIO()` in the Python3 bit of the answer since that Python3 section was added back in 2017. No revision has *ever* mentioned `SocketIO`.

Comment: @paxdiablo My comment was about the above @Alex comment, which from I understand I could use `SocketIO` also. I tried the suggestion and got `AttributeError`.

Comment: If `foo()` throws an exception then stdout will remain captured forever, which may break other tests. It's safer to use [patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) as @asclepius does below.

Comment: @qris, our shop's not usually over-concerned about a possibility like that since we do not distinguish between one failure and a million failures, other than the effort we spend trying to figure out which one is important but it's almost always the earliest one that occurred. For example, no code with failed tests is ever allowed to me merged to mainline. What we would tend to do in that case is catch all possible exceptions, turn off the capture in the handler, and re-throw.

Comment: @paxdiablo But this site is not about answering your exact personal question, it's about sharing knowledge for everyone, and others may well care. Anyway it's just best practice to clean up after yourself, even in tests.

Comment: Good point, @qris, I've added a section at the end to cover this.

Answer (score 66):

This Python 3.6 answer uses [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). It also uses a reusable helper method `assert_stdout`, although this helper is specific to the function being tested.

```
import io
import unittest
import unittest.mock

from .solution import fizzbuzz


class TestFizzBuzz(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def assert_stdout(self, n, expected_output, mock_stdout):
        fizzbuzz(n)
        self.assertEqual(mock_stdout.getvalue(), expected_output)

    def test_only_numbers(self):
        self.assert_stdout(2, '1\n2\n')
```

Note that the `mock_stdout` arg is passed automatically by the `unittest.mock.patch` decorator to the `assert_stdout` method.

A general-purpose `TestStdout` class, possibly a mixin, can in principle be derived from the above.

For those using Python ≥3.4, [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#module-contextlib) also exists, but it seems to serve no benefit over [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch).

Comment: +1. Regarding contextlib: "It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses. However, it is still a useful approach for many utility scripts." and therefore cannot be reliably used.

Comment: On a side note, the **expected** is the first argument on `assertEqual`

Comment: @Begoodpy Not true. The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) merely says `first` and `second`, and it is the final word.

Comment: @Asclepius all tests in the doc, says first, second, but `assertEqual(1, 2)` outputs is `Expected :1 Actual :2`. This is [confirmed](https://sourceforge.net/p/junit/mailman/message/3338997/) by Kent Beck - Junit cocreator - and explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404978/why-are-assertequals-parameters-in-the-order-expected-actual)

Comment: @Begoodpy People's opinions about it are irrelevant. Moreover, your claim that `assertEqual(1, 2)` output is `Expected :1 Actual :2` is totally false. It may have been true in some scenarios in the distant past, but that's gone now. With Python 3.11, the [output is `AssertionError: 1.1 != 2.2`](https://pastebin.com/6jjTdNHp) ([backup](https://archive.ph/Etzgj)). You have produced false claims, multiple times, and nothing that you say can be trusted.

Comment: @Asclepius I understand you are open to more comments on the subject: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53651465/3010217) points to the BDFL discussion on when this actual/expected terminology has changed along the Python versions. As you mention `Python 3` in your answer, note that Python 3.2 uses the actual/expected order and switches to the first/second order later on.

Comment: @Begoodpy Acknowledged. The answer has been updated to mention Python 3.6 which may have been the current version as of 2017 when the answer was created.

Answer (score 24):

If you happen to use [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), it has builtin output capturing. Example (`pytest`-style tests):

```
def eggs():
    print('eggs')


def test_spam(capsys):
    eggs()
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == 'eggs\n'
```

You can also use it with `unittest` test classes, although you need to passthrough the fixture object into the test class, for example via an autouse fixture:

```
import unittest
import pytest


class TestSpam(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _pass_fixtures(self, capsys):
        self.capsys = capsys

    def test_eggs(self):
        eggs()
        captured = self.capsys.readouterr()
        self.assertEqual('eggs\n', captured.out)
```

Check out [Accessing captured output from a test function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) for more info.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the mock package as shown below, which is an example from
https://realpython.com/lessons/mocking-print-unit-tests.

```py
from mock import patch

def greet(name):
    print('Hello ', name)

@patch('builtins.print')
def test_greet(mock_print):
    # The actual test
    greet('John')
    mock_print.assert_called_with('Hello ', 'John')
    greet('Eric')
    mock_print.assert_called_with('Hello ', 'Eric')
```

Comment: I like this one, thank you, it worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46307456/655404) of @Acumenus says:

> It also uses a reusable helper method assert_stdout, **although this helper is specific to the function being tested.**

the bold part seems a big drawback, thus I would do the following instead:

```
# extend unittest.TestCase with new functionality
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def assertStdout(self, expected_output):
        return _AssertStdoutContext(self, expected_output)

    # as a bonus, this syntactical sugar becomes possible:
    def assertPrints(self, *expected_output):
        expected_output = "\n".join(expected_output) + "\n"
        return _AssertStdoutContext(self, expected_output)



class _AssertStdoutContext:

    def __init__(self, testcase, expected):
        self.testcase = testcase
        self.expected = expected
        self.captured = io.StringIO()

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = self.captured
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        captured = self.captured.getvalue()
        self.testcase.assertEqual(captured, self.expected)
```

this allows for the much nicer and much more re-usable:

```
# in a specific test case, the new method(s) can be used
class TestPrint(TestCase):

    def test_print1(self):
        with self.assertStdout("test\n"):
            print("test")
```

by using a straight forward context manager. (It might also be desirable to append `"\n"` to `expected_output` since `print()` adds a newline by default. See next example...)

Furthermore, this very nice variant (for an arbitrary number of prints!)

```
    def test_print2(self):
        with self.assertPrints("test1", "test2"):
            print("test1")
            print("test2")
```

is possible now.

Comment: as your class is called TestCase I'm assuming that you're subclassing unittest.TestCase to expand it and that def test_print(self) is part of class TestPrintClass(TestCase) where TestCase is your extended implementation. Is that correct?

-- maybe stating the obvious here, but it was something that popped up in my head while reading the code

Comment: Absolutely correct. Sorry, for missing the `TestPrintClass` in the example. I will add it in!

Comment: I brought this code in but am getting an error `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'getvalue'`

Comment: Strange. Which python version are you using? The docs do not even mention from which version on the method was included: `https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO.getvalue` (it does for other methods).

Answer (score 2):

You can also capture the standard output of a method using [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=stringio#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
import unittest
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

class TestMyStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    # ...
    def test_stdout(self):
        with redirect_stdout(StringIO()) as sout:
            my_command_that_prints_to_stdout()
        
        # the stream replacing `stdout` is available outside the `with`
        # you may wish to strip the trailing newline
        retval = sout.getvalue().rstrip('\n')

        # test the string captured from `stdout`
        self.assertEqual(retval, "whatever_retval_should_be")
```

Gives you a locally scoped solution. It is also possible to capture the standard error using `contextlib.redirect_stderr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is leaning on the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module rather than `print()`. This module also has a suggestion of when to use `print` [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging):

> Display console output for ordinary usage of a command line script or program

PyTest has [built-in support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html) for testing logging messages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).