# How to test for an error message with Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to find a way to test that my code return the correct error message for a given error with pytest

My code works on a dictionary and in some cases, some keys could be undefined. In the example below, the `tag` variable is provided by the user, and in some cases, that key can be undefined. I then added a try/except statement to catch this exception and return an error message to the user, explaining the issue.

```py
try:
    species = self.species[tag]
except KeyError:
    print(f"Error: the species {tag} is not defined")
```

My issue arise when trying to write a unit test for this code. How could I check that my code return the appropriate error message ? I could write a test who provide willingly a wrong `tag` and then check for stdout, but then I would have to rewrite this test if I decided to change the error message. And it seems not very appropriate in the "Don't Repeat Yourself" approach.

This : [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471) does not answer my question, as I don't raise an exception.

Maybe I'm not even handling correctly the error in the first place and there is a better way to do it with Python.

Comment: properly answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337471/how-to-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest)

Comment: This will not work as the code catch the exception and returns an error message instead. I want to check if the code return the proper error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300627/2650249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should change you code structure to achieve what you wish.

```
class Species:

    def myMethod(tag):
        try:
            species = self.species[tag]
        except KeyError:
            raise YourCustomError(f"Error: the species {tag} is not defined")
```

Then you can write your pytest function to check that YourCustomError is raised when using myMethod with a bad tag. Note that instead of YourCustomError, you can do : `raise KeyError("custom message")`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of using my own exceptions. Maybe it's the better way to handle this issue.

Comment: I tried the ```raise KeyError("custom message")``` you suggested, but I got a quite ugly stack trace, with a first KeyError, then a message saying ```During handling of the above exception, another exception occured``` and then another trace for a second KeyError with my custom message

Comment: Yes the stack trace is not really pretty, but after all it is quite precise. I don't know if this can be changed..