# Is there a way to unit test for multiple prints on terminal?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm currently having trouble unit testing a function that has multiple prints on multiple rows:

```
def state_game(grid, score):

    print(grid[0])
    print(grid[1])
    print(grid[2])
    print(grid[3])
    print(f"Your score is {score}")
    return('------------')
```

What I'm trying to do is test for each row of print whether the line printed on python terminal is correct. So far I've tried this to capture what's printed on terminal :

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
"defining grid"
"defining score"
def test_state_game(self, mock_print):
         state_game(grid, score)
         mock_print.assert_called_with(grid[0])
         mock_print.assert_called_with(grid[1])
         mock_print.assert_called_with(grid[2])
         mock_print.assert_called_with(grid[3])
         mock_print.assert_called_with(f"Your score is {score}")
```

The problem is it seems that when it first tests whether grid[0] is printed on terminal, the test fails showing that expected is grid[0] when "Your score is {score}" has been printed (i.e. the last print of the state_game function). Any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Write unittest for console print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767627/python-write-unittest-for-console-print)

Comment: Well no, the solution you proposed is adapted to some other example. The user isn't testing multiple prints on the terminal

Answer (score 0):

If we set a breakpoint in the debugger, and inspect the contents of the print_mock variable, we can see that `print_mock.call_args_list[]` array contains all of the strings

A little more experimentation give us this  answer:

```python
    from unitest import mock

    def test_state_game(self):
        # 'module' is where 'state_game' is defined
        with mock.patch("module.print") as print_mock:
            state_game(grid, score)
            self.assertEqual(print_mock.call_args_list[0].args[0], grid[0])
            self.assertEqual(print_mock.call_args_list[1].args[0], grid[1])
            self.assertEqual(print_mock.call_args_list[2].args[0], grid[2])
            self.assertEqual(print_mock.call_args_list[3].args[0], grid[3])
            self.assertEqual(print_mock.call_args_list[4].args[0], f"Your score is {score}")
```