# How to write python unit test for the print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am new to writing python unit tests, Please help me to write test cases for the below function which is having only print statements instead of return statements.

```
import os
from pwd import getpwuid
from grp import getgrgid
import time

def info(self):
 if self.f:  // if -f  flag pass with file names then it will be trigger
    for i in self.f:
        owner = getpwuid(os.stat(i).st_uid).pw_name
        group = getgrgid(os.stat(i).st_gid).gr_name
        per = oct(os.stat(i).st_mode)[-3:]
        t = os.stat(i).st_mtime
        print("{} is owned by: {} , group by {} with "
              "permission {} and last modified on {}"
              .format(i, owner, group, per, time.ctime(t)))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Write unittest for console print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767627/python-write-unittest-for-console-print)

Comment: Can you modify `info`? `print` takes a `file` keyword argument to specify a file other than standard output; you can have `info` accept a file-like object and just pass it on to `print`.

Comment: @chepner  Sorry but I didn't understand.  Actually, I am  getting the following error if trying to follow the below answer comment  "  if self.f:  
AtrributeError:  'str' object has no attribute 'f' "

Answer (score 2):

You can use contextlib's [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

```py
import io
import unittest
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

import lib_containing_info

class TestInfo():
    def test_info(self)
        f = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            lib_containing_info.info()  # function being tested
        self.assertRegex(f.getvalue(), r"is owned by: ")
```

Comment: I got the below error when try to implement the above. if self.f: 

AtrributeError:  'str' object has no attribute 'f'

Comment: Where are you using `self.f`? `f` is a local variable, not an instance attribute.