# What is the correct order for actual and expected in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404978/why-are-assertequals-parameters-in-the-order-expected-actual) gives the order `assertEqual(expected, actual)`, albeit for the unittest package.

But Pycharm, with pytest, prints out "Expected:..." and "Actual..." based on the order `actual==expected`.

This is confusing. What is the correct ordering for pytest? The source code and online documentation do not say.

(I note also that JUnit and TestNG disagree on this.)

Comment: There is no ordering. In pytest it's a simple `==` clause. Both sides a equivalent (or not). The developers of your IDE might not have read "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess." from PEP 20.

Comment: I agree. This is rather a Pycharm issue, not `pytest` one. Aside from that, `pytest` support in Pycharm is insufficient anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

BDFL doesn't like [actual/expected terminology](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-December/106954.html) and the docs were [specifically changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue10573) to address this.

If your tooling is expecting arguments in a certain order, then I suppose the most correct thing to do would be to consistently do what works for your tooling.

Comment: I don't understand this.  If pytest is trying to be agnostic, then why are "Expected" and "Actual" clearly printed in the pytest failure message shown in my answer?

Comment: it's pycharm, not pytest

Answer (score 34):

### JUnit

```
assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

### Pytest (Pycharm)

Comments have implied this may be more an issue with the way PyCharm displays the message than `pytest` itself - ie. this message may not exist outside of PyCharm...

```
assert actual == expected
```

For example:

```
def test_actual_expected():
    expected = 4
    actual = 2+1
    assert actual == expected
```

Will fail with message

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a pycharm thing indeed. Running the test without pycharm directly in the console does not show any messages that indicate which side is which one. Even a generated junit xml report does not give any hints in this direction. I guess pycharm just doesn't differentiate between expected and actual. In general it is not possible anyways, especially for arbitrary boolean expressions. E.g. what is the expected/actual value in `assert x and y`?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in PyCharm settings for choosing the order.

It is located in the "Advanced settings" section and is named "Swap the order of actual and expected assertions in Pytest". Unfortunately, it is checked by default (maybe for some historical reason) and thus gives the misleading display generated by default.